# Laravel does not recognize $this->id when getting data in JSON

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

`public function other_children(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\SameModel', 'parent_id', 'parent_id')
        ->where('id','!=', $this->id);
}`

This works when I get data (query log: `... where id != ? ...`, but when I return it in JSON like `return SameModel::with('other_children')->first();` does not work. Query log: `... where id is not null ...`

It does not recognize `$this->id` when getting data with `->with`

Any solution?

Comment: I feel an object is needed to be in place for `$this` to work.

Comment: show more code, are you sure that you have `$this->id` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one model, you don't need to use eager loading:

```
$model = SameModel::first();
$model->other_children;
return $model;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by nested like this

```
$id = $this->id;
return SameModel::with(['other_children' => function ($query) use($id) {
    $query->where('id','!=', $id);
}])->get();
```

In your question `$this` belongs to controller not to Model, this would be the reason to not recognizing `$this->id` in relation method which in model.